# Error : No repository found at http://rlogiacco.github.com/Natural

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Currently I am using Eclipse for Java Developers 2020-12 and while trying to install Natural 0.9 plugin I am encountering an error which is "No repository found at [http://rlogiacco.github.com/Natural"](http://rlogiacco.github.com/Natural%22).
Can someone suggest what should be done to rectify this ?

Comment: Several complaints about this on the [marketplace page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/natural), so I guess it is currently broken.

Comment: Does it work via _Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural/`](https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural/)?

Answer (score 11):

The below worked successfully for me. Hope it works for you too.

From the Eclipse "Help" menu, open "Install New Software..." Add a new site: Button "Add... " in the upper right Enter

Name - Natural
Location - http://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural

Note: Make sure there are no spaces in the Location field value

Comment: This works! For some reason the Eclipse Marketplace is not helping in installing the plugin. But, by this way, I was able to install the plugin (although it asked for installing the unsigned content midway; we have all seen that in Eclipse IDE, just proceeding past it will install the plugin).

Answer (score 0):

From the Eclipse "Help" menu, open "Install New Software..."
Add a new site: Button "Add... " in the upper right
Enter Name: "Natural", Location: "http ://rlogiacco.github.io/ Natural" (the correct link, remove blanks)
Click "Add", select what you want to install, and install.

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclips--> Help-->InstallNewSoftware-->Click on Add button-->Enter Name:"Natural"-->Location= https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural [ Space should not be there]-->Click on Add and and follow Instruction.

This solution is work for me.Refe attached successful Natural plugins installation snap.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfP9D.png)

Answer (score -1):

**Worked for me:-**
Go to Help > Install new software > Add > Give it a name "Natural" > Add http://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural

Comment: This doesn't add anything that the other answers don't already cover.